# why get different at same linux command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

For avoid double run a shell, i write this.

```
[user01@host ~]$ cat singleRun.sh
#/bin/env bash
echo `ps -ef|grep -v 'grep'|grep $0|wc -l`
sleep 1
ps -ef|grep -v 'grep'|grep $0|wc -l
[user01@host ~]$ sh singleRun.sh
2
1
[user01@host ~]$
```

But this result confuse me.

Comment: @Jayesh The `echo` command is a shell builtin, so it should not need a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

When you use command substitution, and new process is spawned. This is why you see two processes in the first case, and only one in the second case.

For example if you change your command script to:

```
echo $(echo $(ps -ef|grep -v 'grep'|grep $0| wc -l))
```

you will see three processes, since there are two command substitutions